# Menu or MenuButton with separate click handler

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm looking for a widget like this.

http://ppt.cc/RPfL

Clicking "View" and triangle (drop down icon) need to perform two different functions.

Clicking the triangle opening the menu.

I tried creating 2 buttons to emulate, but the 2 buttons have extra space in between them.

How can I eliminate the space between buttons or, is there a convenient way to accomplish this?

thank you all!!

Comment: Have you checked http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#menus_category_appearance and http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#toolstrip?

Comment: Yeah, but those are not what i want. I want the widget not only has the pop up function but also the button click function. like the example, I can click the "View" to enter a function, and i can also click the triangle to get the pop up menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [IconMenuButton](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/menu/IconMenuButton.html) (which is a sub class of [IconButton](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/IconButton.html)) will provide what you need.

```
Menu menu = new Menu();

MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem("New");
MenuItem openItem = new MenuItem("Open");
MenuItem saveItem = new MenuItem("Save");
MenuItem saveAsItem = new MenuItem("Save As");

menu.setItems(newItem, openItem, saveItem, saveAsItem);

IconMenuButton menuButton = new IconMenuButton("View", menu);
```

Also check SmartGWT samples I've given in my comment and [RibbonBar sample](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#ribbonbar).

Comment: I've tried this yesterday, but I can't add Click handler like the above example. I always get menu pop up AND the click handler after I click the menu(triangle) Icon. I only want the pop up function after I click the triangle, but I can't achieve this.

Comment: Problem solved, thanks!!  The click issue solved in smartgwt v.4.0